# Create nested <ul> from tab formatted text

Tags: html

Is it possible to create something like:

> - text
>
>   - text
>
>     - text
>
>     text
>
>   text

from tab formatted text like:

```
text
    text
        text
    text
text
```

I can easily wrap every line in `<li>` tag in Sublime by using combination of `Ctrl+Shift+L`, `Home`, `End` to skip the white spaces and edit selected lines simultaneously.
But I have no idea how to create nested lists without doing it manually.

Comment: Create it how? In your IDE, in JavaScript, in Markdown?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear. I have a long text indented with tabs and I'm asking if I can somehow convert it to HTML nested lists, preserving the structure. I have just started learning HTML, I still don't know many tools that I could use.

Answer (score 1):

Use this html code to create nested list

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <body>
   <h2>A Nested List</h2>
    <ul>
     <li>text</li>
      <ul>
        <li>text</li>
        <ul>
            <li>text</li>
        </ul>
       <li>text</li>
     </ul>
       <li>text</li>
    </ul>
   </body>
   </html>
```